# How to print significant variables and coefficients from Logistic regression model output - Dataproc Pyspark

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, logistic-regression, google-cloud-dataproc

I am running a logistic regression model on a dataset with more than 2000 columns in Dataproc Pyspark. I am getting a list of significant coefficients and their index as a result. 
But, I am not able to map those coefficients to the respective important column names.

How do you get significant column names and their coefficients together in pyspark as a dataframe?
Here is my sample code -

```
model_1 = LogisticRegression(labelCol='target_r1', 
                             featuresCol='features',
                             maxIter=20, 
                             regParam=0.03, 
                             elasticNetParam=0.02)

model_op = model_1.fit(train)

print(model_op.coefficients)
```

The results look like:

```
(1925,[1,3,4,6,7,8,11,13,14,16,...],[0.12, 0.1, 1.12,..]
```

As a list of variable index and coefficient values. I want to print the coefficient name instead. How can I print the variable name instead of the index with the coef value?

Comment: check `train.select('features').schema.jsonValue()`, the feature names are saved in one of the `metadata` field.